# how to show the error when missing function is inside an if

Tags: php

Today I noticed that the missing function dosent show an error when is inside an if. And what to see that error, because is hard for debugging

```
<?php if(3 >1): ?>

    <?php echo missingFunction(3); ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <?php echo missingFunction(3); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If I call the function on its own

// This will show that the function is missing

```
<?php echo missingFunction(4); ?>
```

In the beging of the file I have

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Your logic seems unclear, What means the parameters `3` and `4`?

Comment: just simple example the numbers mean nothing

Comment: What error is (not) showing??

Comment: is the function existing in your code? Otherwise, a parse error has to show up.

Comment: missingFunction() is not defined. If the function is inside an if it just stop and everything below is not shown. Like die();

Comment: But if I call the function outside that if, I see the error that this function is not defined.

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function missingFunction() in test.php on line 3` as must to be (recognized inside `if`). Your problem is in another part. Hopefully gives more info.

Comment: Where is missingFunction()...?

Comment: @suresh-g lol, `missingFunction` does not exists, thats the point here...

Answer (score 1):

You can't see error if xy function is inside of a (negative) `if` - only when its triggered. There is no way.

But you can do (check) file like this, and you should write "questionable/suspicious/hidden/if" functions in manually (hardcoded).. better then nothing though.

```
$maybe_fns = (function1,function2); //... you should type in `if` functions here, manually 
$check    = @explode(',', $maybe_fns);

    while (list($key,$xxx) = each($check))
    {
    if(!function_exists($xxx)
    {
    echo '<b>Warning:</b> No function <b>'.$xxx.'</b><br>';
    }
    }
```

May come handy in alpha & beta testings, and its better then reading bunch of functions files for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a function in PHP is only determined at the very last minute when the interpreter executes the statement.

So if you have a missing function inside a condition that never evaluates to `true`, no errors will be triggered.

For example:

```
if (false) {
    this_function_does_not_exist(); // this never gets run
}
// no errors
```

Comment: @NomikOS And that's your actual code? Somehow I don't think we're looking at the right thing here.

Comment: Don't understand you. (The question is not mine). In any case code as is presented it should trigger a fatal error. hmmlollol (the user:) says that he not obtain that error...

Comment: @NomikOS Sorry, I thought you were OP hehe